# How do I convert an integer to a javascript color?

Tags: javascript

I have an integer which I need to convert to a color in javascript.
I am using an MVC model and am trying to replicate a model in a software for a web interface. 
I have the color in integer format from the database. It needs to be converted to a color in javascript.

For example: integers like -12525360, -5952982

I have the code like this :

```
items[x].barStyle = "stroke: Black; fill = Red";
```

So instead of giving the fill:Red, I need to give it the exact color corresponding to the integer value.

This is the code I have written in C#. I need the same thing in javascript.
Here resourcecolor= the integer input.

```
     var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(resourcecolor);
     ti.color = Color.FromArgb(bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: how does the integer looks like? Which javascript color format do you want to get?

Comment: `if(integer == 1) color == "red" else if(integer == 2) color == "green"`?

Comment: give an example. what have you tried?

Comment: Still not enough information. What do the numbers represent exactly? What do you mean by "color" her? You cannot convert something into a "color", only into a *representation* of a color. So, what is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: From where to you get this integer value? From .NET code?

Comment: What do the integers mean? Do they correspond to RGB?

Comment: I get this integer value from a JSON result which extracts the data from the database.

Comment: That's irrelevant to the question, what do they *mean*?

Comment: Are you able to manipulate the value from .NET code before its sent to  the client (javascript)

Comment: Yes, I can manipulate the value before it is sent to the client.

Comment: @user1585020 You should accept one of the answer to your question.

Answer (score 35):

In javascript, you express a ARGB color that is to be used with canvas or css as a string like `"rgba(0-255,0-255,0-255,0-1)"`.

You can convert the integer to that string format with this function:

```
function toColor(num) {
    num >>>= 0;
    var b = num & 0xFF,
        g = (num & 0xFF00) >>> 8,
        r = (num & 0xFF0000) >>> 16,
        a = ( (num & 0xFF000000) >>> 24 ) / 255 ;
    return "rgba(" + [r, g, b, a].join(",") + ")";
}
toColor(-5952982)
//"rgba(165,42,42,1)"
toColor(-12525360)
//"rgba(64,224,208,1)"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ectpk/

Comment: This one returns an accurate color!

Answer (score 12):

Really simply:

```js
colorString = "#" + colour.toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
```

But when I actually reference it I also remove the alpha from the integer and set the style colour at the same time, so the whole line is:

```js
document.getElementById('selectColourBtn').style.color = "#" +
    (colour & 0x00FFFFFF).toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
```

Comment: To ensure that it works for numbers such as 0 it needs to be padded. A simple one-liner would then be: `"#" + (number & 0x00FFFFFF).toString(16).padStart(6, '0')`

Comment: Good catch! Updated answer. Thanks @ackh.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

hexColour = yourNumber.toString(16)

You may want to normalize 'yourNumber' too.

Comment: To put a little more context, in pure Javascript, this would work to convert a number to color.  td.style.backgroundColor = "#" + value.toString(16);

Comment: It doesn't work for some cases, for example the int value 0 can't convert to desire '#000000'

Comment: This is a nice one liner: ('#' + mynum.toString(16).padStart(6, '0'));

Comment: Thanks, this the proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the comments on the question it seems you are able to manipulate the value on the server before its sent to the client. If you are using .NET I suggest using the `ColorTranslator`

```
int intColor = -12525360;
string htmlColor = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(intColor)); //#40E0D0
```

Or this (if you need the alpha channel):

```
   int intColor = -12525360;
   Color c = Color.FromArgb(intColor);
   string htmlColor = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                        "rgba({0},{1},{2},{3})", c.R, c.G, c.B, c.A / 255f);
```

Comment: This is also works, though if there is a `rgba` format in .NET, you should use that because the `#xxxxxx`-format cannot encode alpha

Comment: Btw I'm not sure one can do what I edited the post to be in .NET but the alpha value in the css rgba format is between 0-1 (float), not 0-255. There should probably be some kind of cast there?

Comment: @Esailija yes, having 255 as a float value (by adding the "f") and using `InvariantCulture` (to always format the float with a ".") should do it.

Answer (score 1):

***Disclosure***: I'm the author of the library suggested below.

If you want to use a library rather than coding it yourself, the [pusher.color](http://surfacecurve.org/libraries/color) Javascript library supports integer to HTML color conversions:

```
// Will set c to "rgba(105,80,131,1.0)"
var c = pusher.color('packed_argb', -9875325).html()
```

Or if you wanted a different format:

```
var colorObject = pusher.color('packed_argb', -9875325);
var htmlString = colorObject.html();          // i.e. "rgba(105,80,131,1.0)"
var colorName  = colorObject.html('keyword'); // closest named color
var hexString  = colorObject.html('hex6');    // "#695083"
```

Internally the library uses code very similar to [Esailija's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija) answer.

Answer (score 0):

one line code by [js template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
let colorStr = `#${(colorNum).toString(16).padStart(6, '0')}`;
```

For example:

```js
const colorNum = 0x00f0ff;
const colorStr = `#${(colorNum).toString(16).padStart(6, '0')}`;
console.log(colorStr);
// output: #00f0ff
```