# How can i convert ARGB to HEX in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, argb

I want to convert ARGB colors to CSS-compatible hex

for example:

`-1` should be converted to `#FFFFFF`

or

`-16777216` to `#000000`

How can I do that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This discards any alpha component

```
function argbToRGB(color) {
    return '#'+ ('000000' + (color & 0xFFFFFF).toString(16)).slice(-6);
}
```

Your colors are signed 32-bits and full alpha (0xFF) makes the numbers negative. This code works even for unsigned numbers.

Comment: how do you reverse the process in javascript? Starting from a hex value and working towards the argb value? Been looking for a while now and didn't find any solution :(

Comment: @Jorrex not sure if you're still looking, but I needed that, too, and found it here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/g02s07n4/embedded/result/ thanks to this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29101148/5758637

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like this:

```
function convertToColorString (argb){ 
   return '#'+ ('000000' + (argb+16777216).toString(16)).slice(-6); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this question: [How do I convert an integer to a javascript color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866781/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-a-javascript-color)

My reply to that question was roughly to suggest that, if you want to use a library rather than coding it yourself, the [**pusher.color Javascript library**](http://surfacecurve.org/libraries/color) supports integer to HTML color conversions:

```
// Will set c to "#695083"
var c = pusher.color('packed_argb', -9875325).hex6();
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bcronin/7LP8B/18/) if you want to try the above out.

Also, let me add the disclaimer that I wrote the library mentioned above.