# Convert 8-digit hex colors to rgba colors?

Tags: css, colors, hex, rgba

Everything I've found on this subject simply converts the hex to rgb and then adds an alpha of 1.  I want to get the intended alpha from the hex digits as well.

A color such as `#949494E8` or `#DCDCDC8F` clearly has an alpha value that's not 0 or 1.

Comment: How do you intend to convert these? By hand? Using a preprocessor? Programmatically, using what language?

Comment: Also, your syntax appears to be incorrect. 8 digit hex typically follows the AARRGGBB ([ARGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space#ARGB)) format, i.e. the first two digits belong to the alpha channels. It seems like you are using the last two digits for the alpha channel.

Comment: http://bricss.net/post/12423845540/working-with-8-digit-hex-colors-argb-in-internet

Comment: These are hex colors from a Textmate theme.  I was trying to convert them to RGBA so I can update and port the theme to LESS.

Comment: @Terry: As that article states, not every implementation uses the same representation. I don't think there is a general notation that is either correct or incorrect - it depends entirely on the implementation. Interestingly, [CSS Color level 4 actually uses the RRGGBBAA format](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#hex-notation).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I have made a quick JSfiddle form that allows you to convert from 8-digit hex code into CSS rgba values ;)

https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/g02s07n4/embedded/result/

The basis is rather simple — to split the string you have provided into parts of 2-digits, and perform conversion into percentage ratios for the alpha channel, and to decimals for the RGB channels. The markup is as follow:

```
<form action="">
    <select id="format">
        <option value="rgba">RGBa: RRGGBBAA</option>
        <option value="argb">aRGB: AARRGGBB</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="hex" value="#949494E8" />
    <button>Convert</button>
</form>
<p id="rgba"></p>
```

The logic:

```
// Remove hash
var hex = $('#hex').val().slice(1);

// Split to four channels
var c = hex.match(/.{1,2}/g);

// Function: to decimals (for RGB)
var d = function(v) {
    return parseInt(v, 16);
};
// Function: to percentage (for alpha), to 3 decimals
var p = function(v) {
    return parseFloat(parseInt((parseInt(v, 16)/255)*1000)/1000);
};

// Check format: if it's argb, pop the alpha value from the end and move it to front
var a, rgb=[];
if($('#format').val() === 'argb') {
    c.push(c.shift());
}

// Convert array into rgba values
a = p(c[3]);
$.each(c.slice(0,3), function(i,v) {
    rgb.push(d(v));
});
```

The gist of conversion is as follow:

- Converting the RGB channels in hex, into decimal values. This is done by using `parseInt(hexValue, 16)`.
- Converting the alpha channel in hex, into percentage ratio. This is done by simply converting it to decimal values (see above point), and calculating its relative value to 255.

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was on line 34, i changed from `c.unshift(c.pop())` to `c.push(c.shift())`.

Comment: @Noitidart Can't believe it has been broken for so long. Thanks for fixing it, updated it.

Comment: Heroes we need.

Comment: Yes, I knew how to do this already, but take some karma for making such a nice time saving tool for the rest of us.

Indeed, a hero.

Comment: Hi, I'm going over your script line-by-line to learn. I've been looking at the Docs to understand what:                                                                                             **var c = hex.match(/.{1,2}/g);** does. In particular the **'/.{1,2}/g'** parameter. So for I understand that the match method is using a RegExp() object to match the #hex input elements' value string against **'.{1,2}/g'** but what exactly is **'.{1,2}/g'**? and can someone explain to me what this line is doing. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Here is a little tooltip for you :**

In this case `#DCDCDC8F` the `DC` is `alpha` = 220,

**Hex to Decimal [ DC ]:**

1. first place D = 13 * 16^1 = 208
2. second place C = 12 * 16^0 = 12
3. sum = 12 + 208 = 220

**then 220 / 255 = 0.86 opacity.**

[image]

**The bytes are stored in memory on a little-endian machine in the order AABBGGRR**

Check this : http://www.statman.info/conversions/hexadecimal.html

Comment: I believe these numbers (from Textmate themes) are RRGGBBAA.  If I use `#F5AA00` which is "selection color", I get the correct orange `rgba(245, 170, 0, 1.0)`. But I need the alpha of `91`, from the original `F5AA0091`.

Comment: what math gets you the alpha value for the 2-character hex?

Comment: Do you want the math formula??

Comment: I found this... tedious, but it works.  Then I assume I divide by 255.  http://www.palmantics.com/html/hexadecimal/

Comment: I have extended my answer a bit to provide better insight into problem.