# Transparent color doesn't work inside Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have created a contact-us form in bootstrap with transparent view for input box. Its worked good in firebox browser, not not shows its transparent property in chrome browser. i dnt know how to fix this issue. if any one know please help me to fix it.

see this

**Firefox View:**

[image]

**Chrome View:**

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the sample code that you already tried?

Comment: You're using 8-digit hex colors which aren't currently supported on Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a color code that isn't supported in Chrome that's why it's not correctly displaying on your browser.

[image]

Instead of using `background-color: #ffffff1a` on `.form-control` you should use a RGBA instead. In your case use `rgba(255,255,255,0.101)`

> 8-digit hexadecimal values are ignored as they are currently deemed invalid by Chrome's CSS parser.

You can always convert 8-hex colors into RGBA colors with [this CodePen tool](https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/g02s07n4/embedded/result/), credit goes to [Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29101148/6331369)

For more information on 8-digit hexadecimal values read [this very interesting thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015302/css-hexadecimal-rgba)

Comment: Always happy to help!