# Alpha channel and opacity in a Bootstrap theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, ui.bootstrap

I am trying to port an accordion control to a ui.bootstrap accordion.  Most elements that I am dealing with in the ui.bootstrap version are panel classed elements in vanilla Bootstrap.

I have created (using the [theme customizer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/)) css to set the backgrounds, borders and text coloring, but I cannot seem to set the opacity in the customizer, and it seems to have no effect when I hand-set it in css.

I don't know much about Less.  Is opacity not supported on these panel elements due to competing or inherited styles that I am just not seeing?

In my css bootstrap theme, I have tried setting things like the following:

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000b3;
  border-color: #000000;
}
```

For an example of what I am trying to achieve, see below:
[image]

Comment: Hex8 isn't well supported...could that be the issue. Why not use RGBA?

Comment: try using '!important;' tag to overwrite the inherited styles.

Comment: @Paulie_D I will try that out, thanks!

Comment: @PrachiMishra !important did not see to do it interestingly.

Comment: @Paulie_D RGBA worked like a charm.  If you write an answer, I will be sure to mark it and upvote it.

Comment: @CodeWarrior Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the [**8 digit hex**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation) color notation being used.

```
background-color: #000000b3;
```

Whilst there is [**support**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa) in maany modern browsers (not IE or Edge) this may not be recognised by CSS pre-processors or some IDEs.

[image]

I would suggest that you employ RGBA notation as an alternative or a fallback.

```
background-color: #000000b3; 
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7)
```

A handy converter can be found right here on [**Stack Overflow - Convert 8-digit hex colors to rgba colors?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100161/convert-8-digit-hex-colors-to-rgba-colors)