# Hex code of background-color is not displayed by Edge

Tags: html, css

I use the following simple `HTML` and `CSS` code:

```css
.content {
  background-color: #e9ddafff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
Content goes here.
</div>
```

This code works perfectly in all browsers except for **Edge**. When you open it in Edge the browser does not recognize the `background-color`. I guess somehow Edge cannot deal with the hex code `#e9ddafff` because when I change it to `red` everything works.

Do you have any idea what I need to change in my code to also make it work in the **Edge** browser?

JSfiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vf0L974e/).

Comment: use rgba, it's not yet supported this syntax https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa

Comment: in case you want to convert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100161/convert-8-digit-hex-colors-to-rgba-colors