# convert Android color to HEX or RGB

Tags: javascript

I have a set of numbers like `4294933099`, `4283744614`, `4293898800` that I want to use in a web page as RGB or HEX colors.

I never saw this type of color format before but googling lead me to [this page](https://convertingcolors.com/android-color-4294933099.html) that identifies those numbers as Android `android.graphics.Color`, what I want is having my own JavaScript function that converts those humbers to safe Hex or RGB colors to use in a web page.

[image]

Comment: I think this should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866781/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-a-javascript-color, check the 4th answer with 21 votes, let me know if it worked for you will add it as a reference in the answer so it will be helpful for future reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually android color are just decimal numbers, so if you convert them to hexadecimal strings you reach the hex color but as ARGB.

```
hexARGBColor = color.toString(16);
```

Answer (score 2):

`android.graphics.Color`s are in hexadecimal `AARRGGBB` (Alpha-Red-Green-Blue) format, converted to decimals.

For example, `4294933099` is `FFFF7A6B` in hexadecimal, so it becomes `rgba(255, 122, 107, 1)` or `#FF7A6BFF`.

If you want to use the `rgba()` syntax, you can use this division approach, that avoids converting numbers to hex:

```js
function androidToRgba(color){
  const colorArray = []
  for(let i=0; i<4; i++){
    colorArray.push(color % 256)
    color>>>=8
  }
  const alpha = colorArray.pop() / 255
  return `rgba(${colorArray.reverse()},${alpha})`
}

console.log(androidToRgba(4294933099))
console.log(androidToRgba(4283744614))
console.log(androidToRgba(4293898800))
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the new `#RRGGBBAA` color syntax, or ignore the alpha and use standard HEX (`#RRGGBB`), you can use this instead:

```js
function androidToHex(color){
  const [, alpha, ...colorArray] = ('00000000' + color.toString(16)).slice(-8).match(/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})/i)
  return `#${colorArray.join('')}${alpha}`
}

console.log(androidToHex(4294933099))
console.log(androidToHex(4283744614))
console.log(androidToHex(4293898800))
```

Although both of the above solutions work, I **highly recommend the former**, as  the `rgba()` syntax **has better support** than `#RRGGBBAA`, and the first function is also [around **9 times faster**](https://perf.link/#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%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).